# Signing a public key using the specified CA key with paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko, openssh

Is there any equivalent of `ssh-keygen -s` option in paramiko?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no ready-made code in Paramiko to do the signing. Paramiko might have quite enough functionality to help with a signing implementation, but it definitely won't be a single-method call. (Paramiko supports certificate validation though).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Do You think, invoking ssh-keygen with proper args by os api will be easier and faster?

Comment: Implementation-wise - definitely.